# How to Probe Azure Event Grid

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I am using Azure Event Grid to send custom events. All works fine, but now I want to create a health check service which would probe all of my services to see if they are working. For this I am using [AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks). But it doesn't support Azure Event Grid.

Is there a way I could probe event grid to check that it's working without sending actual event?

Comment: are you using an Event Domain?

Comment: @RomanKiss What do you mean by `Event Domain`? I am using Event Grid for domain events throughout my application.

Comment: My question has been related to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-domains#event-domain-overview . This is a recently preview, where the EventDomain model can help for managing/auditing of the custom events. The EventDomains allow for domain-scope subscriptions. In other words, you can create your custom loopback probe on the domain scope level.

Comment: you can test this new preview using the following tester tool: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester

Answer (score 7):

There is a health probe endpoint for each custom topic.

Here is an example of an endpoint you can ping:

https://.westcentralus-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/health

Comment: Thanks, is there some document about this health probe endpoint or it is just loopback with OK response?

Comment: @dbarkol, some question as above, is there any documentation for this? Although that is something, I just realized I cannot check if my access token is valid for Event Grid as I can just ping it from anywhere.

Comment: This is just a health probe to see if the endpoint is available. There isn't any documentation on this, it's just an artifact of the design and how it's load-balanced.